# Не получается загрузить прошивку на esp32cam через Thonny

Tags: python, esp32, micropython

Я использую esp32cam mb для загрузки, во всех туторах не используют эту плату, поэтому не могу точно определить, что делаю не так. Пробовал загружать разные прошивки для micropython, но исход вечно почти один и тот же, лиюо выдает липовую ошибку, либо консоль спамит сообщениями ">>> MERA module (KAKI5) with ESP32" либо же ",len:13816
load:0x40080400,len:3340
entry 0x40080618"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]